# How does Fin "know" not to go past its type bound?

Tags: idris, idris2

How does `Fin` actually work?

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat

data Fin : (n : Nat) -> Type where
  FZ : Fin (S k) 
  FS : Fin k -> Fin (S k)
```

- Where does `k` come from?
- Why isn't `FZ` always the value of `(n: Nat)` + 1?
- How does `Fin` "know" not to exceed its type bound?

This [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/g/idris-lang/c/CUwxhmyOp_Y) talks about implicits, but I'm lost as to how and where these values come from.

Given this basic example:

```
t1 : Fin 3 
t1 = FZ
```

What is `t1`'s *value*? t1's *type* is `Fin 3`, but FZ experimentally (appears) to represent zero. Which is why we can "count" with it just like we do with `Nat`:

```
t2 : Fin 3 
t3 = FS (FS FZ)  -- this is equal to 2?
```

But this confuses me given the constructor!

```
FZ : Fin (S k)
```

If we're saying that `t1` has type `Fin 3`, does that mean that `k` takes on the value of the `n` in the type? If that were the case, and `FZ` calls `S` on that `Nat`, then why isn't `FZ` representing *4*?

This is obviously *not* the case.

So I'm completely and absolutely lost on how FZ acts like 0, and where `k` comes from, and how the compiler knows when `k` has become >= `n` *just based on this data type*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what's confusing you is that you're thinking `k` is the value of the `Fin n`. It's not. It's just book-keeping to make sure the `Fin n` is always less than `n`.

**Where does k come from?**

In

```
  FZ : Fin (S k)
```

`k` is an (erased) implicit argument. It's shorthand for

```
  FZ : {0 k : _} -> Fin (S k)
```

so it's passed implicitly, but it's still an argument to `FZ`. In most cases, it can be unambiguously inferred from the context. The compiler will tell you if it can't.

**Why isn't `FZ` always the value of `(n: Nat) + 1`?**

`FZ` always represents zero*. This

```
t1 : Fin 3 
t1 = FZ
```

is the same as

```
t1 : Fin 3 
t1 = FZ {k = 2}
```

It's a zero that's less than three. These are also all zero

```
a : Fin 1
a = FZ

b : Fin 4
b = FZ

c : Fin 100
c = FZ
```

**How does Fin "know" not to exceed its type bound?**

Since `FZ` is always zero, and `FS FZ` is always one, and so on, it's impossible to express a `Fin n` with value greater than or equal to `n`. Let's try to create a `Fin 2` of value two.

```
x : Fin 2
x = FS (FS FZ)  -- this won't compile
```

To see why this won't compile, fill in the implicits (note that `FS` also has an implicit argument called `k`):

```
x : Fin 2
x = FS {k = 1} (FS {k = 0} (FZ {k = ?!?}))
```

We're creating a `Fin 2` so the outer-most `FS` must have `S k = 2` so `k = 1`. Each successive `FS` we go down we reduce `k` by one (see the argument to `FS` is `Fin k` to produce a `Fin (S k)` - so one less). Eventually we reach `FZ` but by this point there's isn't a `Nat` to represent this value of `k`. The compiler balks with such a statement

```
If Data.Fin.FZ: When unifying:
    Fin (S ?k)
and:
    Fin 0
Mismatch between: S ?k and 0.

(Interactive):1:17--1:19
 1 | :let x = FS (FS FZ)
                     ^^
```

You can do the same for a `Fin 2` of value three etc. Have a try.

**Other qus**

Given

```
t1 : Fin 3 
t1 = FZ
```

What is `t1`'s value? *It's `FZ`, and `FZ` represents zero*.

```
t2 : Fin 3 
t2 = FS (FS FZ)  -- this is equal to 2?
```

*Yes, it's two.*

If we're saying that `t1` has type `Fin 3`, does that mean that `k` takes on the value of the `n` in the type? If that were the case, and `FZ` calls `S` on that `Nat`, then why isn't `FZ` representing 4? *`S k` takes on the value of `n`.*

*this is actually a matter convention, but I'll avoid confusing things by going into that

Comment: This was a great explanation! Clarifying the implicits made it click!